# Is there a way to use either a nz-checkbox Or nz-checkbox-group Or nz-checkbox-wrapper inside a reactive form

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

Following code works great if is used independently,

```
<nz-checkbox-group [(ngModel)]="field.options" [formControlName]="field.id" (ngModelChange)="updateValue($event)"></nz-checkbox-group>
```

Angular6.0 does not allow [(ngModel)] with FormGroup (Reactive Forms). As is deprecated in angular 6.0 and will be removed in angular 7.0 version.

Is there any method to write nz-checkbox-group for ReactiveForm ?

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar problem solved that using the following method. [SourceCode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jykn8w?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: 'nz-demo-checkbox-layout',
template: `
    <nz-checkbox-wrapper style="width: 100%;" (nzOnChange)="log($event)">
      <div nz-row >
       <div [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
        <label nz-checkbox nzValue="A" formControlName="a">A</label>
        <label nz-checkbox  nzValue="B" formControlName="b">B</label>
        <label nz-checkbox nzValue="C" formControlName="c">C</label>
        <label nz-checkbox nzValue="D" formControlName="d">D</label>
       </div>
      </div>
    </nz-checkbox-wrapper>`
})
export class NzDemoCheckboxLayoutComponent {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
    public myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        a:this.fb.control(true),
        b:this.fb.control(false),
        c:this.fb.control(false),
        d:this.fb.control(false)
    }); 
}
```